# ASP.Net Core MVC Passing model to controller empty why?

Tags: asp.net-core, model, controller, return

I have a razor view page which is showing data from my database. I have a submit button which calls the action with the model but in the controller the model is empty. Can some please explain what I am doing wrong? Here is my razor page code:

```html
                    <div class="row align-items-start mt-4">
                        <div class="col-12">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" asp-controller="CustomerDetails" asp-action="UpdateCustomer" asp-route-customermodel="@Model.customer"><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span> Submit</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Here is my controller code: -

```html
        public IActionResult UpdateCustomer(Customer customermodel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                customerRepository.update(customermodel);
            } else
            {
                string error = ModelState.Values.ToString();
            }

            return View("../Home/Index");
        }
```

I found the line of code below which seems to work but again I have to add 50 property names rather than just the model. Seems like this is not the correct approach or I am doing it wrong.

```html
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CourseID,Title,Credits,DepartmentID")]Course course)
```

Thanks for any advice,

Answer (score 1):

If you use `asp-route-customermodel="@Model.customer"`,you will get:

```
<a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="/CustomerDetails/UpdateCustomer?customermodel=ClientSideDemo3.Models.Customer"><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span> Submit</a>
```

`asp-route-xxx`cannot bind model,here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

View:

```
 <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" asp-controller="CustomerDetails" asp-action="UpdateCustomer" asp-route-Id="@Model.customer.Id" asp-route-Name="@Model.customer.Name"><span class="fas fa-plus-circle"></span> Submit</a>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer but my problem is I have around 50 properties in my model.

Comment: You'd better to use a form,and make the inputs hidden.

Comment: Surely not for every property? I have my model bound to all the controls where the user makes changes so all I want to do is post it back to an action to update the database. Any help much appreciated.